# r markdown vitae package "Undefined control sequence" error when knitting to vitae predefined cv templates

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, tinytex

In R markdown, I'm getting an "Undefined control sequence" error when knitting any of the out-of-the-box cv templates (awesomecv, moderncv, etc.) included in the "vitae" package. I am using tinytex. Here is the out-of-the-box code I execute (too long to include whole thing in an SO post, so "Publications" section removed):

````
---
address: School of Physics & Chemistry, cole Normale Suprieure
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %Y')`"
email: Marie.Curie@ens.fr
github: mariecurie
linkedin: mariecurie
name: Marie
output:
  pdf_document: default
  vitae::awesomecv: default
phone: +1 22 3333 4444
position: Professor
surname: Curie
twitter: mariecurie
www: mariecurie.com
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE)
library(vitae)
```

# Some stuff about me

 * I poisoned myself doing research.
 * I was the first woman to win a Nobel prize
 * I was the first person and only woman to win a Nobel prize in two different sciences.

# Education


# Nobel Prizes

```{r}
library(tibble)
library(vitae)
tribble(
  ~Year, ~Type, ~Desc,
  1903, "Physics", "Awarded for her work on radioactivity with Pierre Curie and Henri Becquerel",
  1911, "Chemistry", "Awarded for the discovery of radium and polonium"
) %>% 
  brief_entries(
    glue::glue("Nobel Prize in {Type}"),
    Year, 
    Desc
  )
```

# Publications
...
````

And here is the error I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.104 \briefsection
                   {\briefitem{Nobel Prize in Physics}{1903}{Awarded for her...

Error: Failed to compile filename.tex. See https://yihui.name/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See filename.log for more info.
Execution halted
```

I'm using R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) on Windows >= 8 x64, with RStudio.

Comment: Can you share the intermediate `filename.tex` file?

Answer (score 2):

You list `pdf_document` first in the `output` section of your YAML header.  That means it's the default output format.  It appears that the `vitae` package generates code that requires a LaTeX package that isn't automatically included with `pdf_document`.

However, when I switch the order to

```
output:
  vitae::awesomecv: default
  pdf_document: default
```

the default is the `vitae::awesomecv` format, and in that format, things work.  If you're using RStudio, you can also use the dropdown menu on `Knit` to make this swap automatically by clicking on `Knit to awesomecv`.

**Edited to add**:  In fact, as pointed out in the comments, it probably makes sense to delete the `pdf_document` line entirely, in which case it can be simplified to

```
output: vitae::awesomecv
```

Comment: It probably makes sense to get rid of `pdf_document: default` completely.